# when i set property(retain), one "self" = one "retain"?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, retain

although I'm about to finish my first app, I'm still confused about the very basic memory management..I've read through many posts here and apple document, but I'm still puzzled..
For example..I'm currently doing things like this to add a label programmatically:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *showTime;
@sythesize showTime;

showTime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 4, 200, 36)];
[self.showTime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time]];
[self.showTime setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaRoundedLT-Bold" size:23]];
[self.showTime setTextColor:numColor];
self.showTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self addSubview:self.showTime];
[showTime release];
```

this is my current practice, for UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView, etc...
[Alloc init] it without self., coz I know this will retain twice..
but after the allocation, I put back the "self." to set the attributes..

My gut feel tells me I am doing wrong, but it works superficially and I found no memory leak in analyze and instruments.. can anyone give my advice? when I use "self." to set text and set background color, does it retain one automatically? THX so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you create a property with a "retain" attribute, using the "self" pointer to set the property itself (which is different than setting some aspect of the property, such as the text or font), will add a retain count.  It will not, however, add a retain count when you simply access it, as you are doing when you are setting the text, font, textColor, etc.  Nor will it add a retain count, as you've noted yourself, when you set the instance variable directly (by leaving out the `self` pointer).

Your "showTime" will have 1 retain count by the time you reach the last line shown here.

Retain #1 = `[UILabel alloc]`

Retain #2 = `[self addSubview:self.showTime];` (and to be clear, it's the `addSubview` method call that is adding the retain count in this case... not the `self.showTime` accessor).

`[showTime release]` removes one of the retain counts, so one remains.

Unless you are accessing the label again, to change the text, font, etc, you probably don't need to create the property at all.

Comment: Thx for your quick response! may I ask a follow up question?
does it make sense if I put [showTime release]; [showTime release]; which means release twice in order to dealloc the label when I don't need it anymore?

Comment: No! You shouldn't call release at that position in the first place but rather in your dealloc. The view you add it to takes care of its own retain/release balance. Furthermore, at least in your next project, use ARC. It's really the right way to do it these days and not less professional to not manage the memory yourself.

Comment: I really appreciate your "not less professional to not manage the memory yourself", thx! actually I found that I have created a lot of objects and cannot destroy efficiently in instrument tool, and if problem persists, I will definitely change to ARC right in this project..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you give property to any element then what that means is, you are providing an automatic getter/setter for that element.

```
 @property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *showTime;
 @synthesize showTime;
```

Now, you HAVE TO initialize the element with self in order to access these getters/setters.

Hence, always do,

```
 self.showTime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 4, 200, 36)];
```

You are retaining twice, so keep the allocated object in autoreleased mode.

```
 self.showTime = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 4, 200, 36)] autorelease];
```

Now, when you want to get the object for example to give value or to change background color etc,

```
 [self.showTime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time]];
```

OR

```
 [showTime setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time]];
```

anything would be fine.

But, in the DEALLOC section, you again need self to set it nil.

```
 self.showTime = nil;
```

Actually, the retain property generates a setter method, which is like below.

```
 - (void)setShowTime:(UILabel *)label {
     if (showTime != label) {
         [showTime release];
         showTime = [label retain];
     }
 }
```

Hence, when we are dealing with memory changes, i.e ALLOCation or Deallocation, at that time, use SELF.

However, this is my understanding of usage of self. Any other ideas, always welcomed!

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: heh, reading these post about property-retain-count and smiling. Use arc and be happy ))Though it was also a hard time for me in former times

Comment: Yea, but this is one of the important things to know. ARC does this automatically. Hence, it is something top of the layer of memory-management. Its always good to know how its cooking inside, right? :)

Comment: besides its scary to know that it'll handle on its own. Imagine lots and lots and lots of autoreleased variables. Although ARC is much better and nothing like it would crash, but then this is the tough way and if you know this, you would know when things get really complex :)

Comment: thx very much!!I like to accept your answer your answer too, if I have 2 votes!and yes..I will change to ARC soon, but I would feel guilty if I dun get through these "basic" stuff....

Comment: Walter - Yes, you have to have the basic knowledge about memory management. And you can always do upvotes btw! 
@Stas - Yes, Me too using ARC only, but you never know!

Comment: I need 4 reputation more to do upvotes~ promise to do it later XD

Comment: `self.showTime = nil;` in dealloc is not recommended due to issues with KVO